# Fortify : XSLT Injection attacks fix

Tags: c#, xslt, saxon, fortify-source

Fortify scan results show me a xslt injection attack warning on the below code

```
  public Saxon.Api.XsltTransformer transformer = null;

  using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("C://Document.xsl", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)) **//warning source**
  using (System.IO.Stream xslStream = reader.BaseStream)
  {
     transformer = new Saxon.Api.Processor().NewXsltCompiler().Compile(xslStream).Load(); **//warning line**
  }
```

How can I resolve this situation ?

Note : it doesn't give any error it says this line of code is suspicious

Comment: I believe that Fortify will warn any time you read and marshal an external resource and don't have any explicit checks on the content to ensure that someone malicious doesn't inject something in the payload that you blindly parse. It might be helpful if you provided more info about the Fortify warning, with the code and descriptive text, for context.

Comment: In terms of meaningful and error and hassle free use of the API I would strongly suggest not to open a StreamReader with an explicit encoding but rather to pass Saxon a Stream so that it or rather its XML parser can detect the encoding based on the XML declaration and/or BOM. In general, as soon as your main stylesheet uses `xsl:import/xsl:include`, you also need to set up a base uri on the compiler.

Comment: Well, if you trust the contents of Document.xsl then this code is perfectly safe, and if you don't, then it isn't. But I don't know how you tell Fortify that you trust it.